# Regex to split on successions of newline characters

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I'm trying to split a string on newline characters (catering for Windows, OS X, and Unix text file newline characters). If there are any succession of these, I want to split on that too and not include *any* in the result.

So, for when splitting the following:

```
"Foo\r\n\r\nDouble Windows\r\rDouble OS X\n\nDouble Unix\r\nWindows\rOS X\nUnix"
```

The result would be:

```
['Foo', 'Double Windows', 'Double OS X', 'Double Unix', 'Windows', 'OS X', 'Unix']
```

What regex should I use?

Comment: Are you concerned about other vertical whitespace? \r\n is DOS, but there are still other possible vertical whitespace such as vertical tab and Unicode NBSP, PS, LS, NNBSP. You might want to check if Python supports the concept of generic newline. Perl has \v and \R which match any generic vertical whitespace or linefeed respectively. If not, if you want the Unicode characters, add in those to your character classes [\r\n]+ and the Python equivalent of looking for those Unicode characters.

Answer (score 24):

If there are no spaces at the starts or ends of the lines, you can use `line.split()` with no arguments. It will remove doubles.
.
If not, you can use `[a for a a.split("\r\n") if a]`.

EDIT: the `str` type also has a method called "splitlines".

`"Foo\r\n\r\nDouble Windows\r\rDouble OS X\n\nDouble Unix\r\nWindows\rOS X\nUnix".splitlines()`

Answer (score 11):

The simplest pattern for this purpose is `r'[\r\n]+'` which you can pronounce as "one or more carriage-return or newline characters".

Answer (score 5):

```
re.split(r'[\n\r]+', line)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> s="Foo\r\n\r\nDouble Windows\r\rDouble OS X\n\nDouble Unix\r\nWindows\rOS X\nUnix"
>>> import re
>>> re.split("[\r\n]+",s)
['Foo', 'Double Windows', 'Double OS X', 'Double Unix', 'Windows', 'OS X', 'Unix']
```

Answer (score 0):

Paying attention to the greediness rules for patterns:

```
pattern = re.compile(r'(\r\n){2,}|(\n\r){2,}|(\r){2,}|(\n){2,}')
paragraphs = pattern.split(text)
```

Comment: This will add `None` when not matching.