# Why does this work in Python 3 IDLE on Windows and not in the terminal on Ubuntu?

Tags: python, ubuntu, io, python-idle

I have a program where I use `input()` to take input from STDIN.

I use the input to read the first word from a line and use it as a dictionary key, with every subsequent word added to a list which is the value of the aformentioned key.

The input is in a file `names.txt`:

```
Victor Bertha Amy Diane Erika Clare
Wyatt Diane Bertha Amy Clare Erika
Xavier Bertha Erika Clare Diane Amy
Yancey Amy Diane Clare Bertha Erika
Zeus Bertha Diane Amy Erika Clare

Amy Zeus Victor Wyatt Yancey Xavier
Bertha Xavier Wyatt Yancey Victor Zeus
Clare Wyatt Xavier Yancey Zeus Victor
Diane Victor Zeus Yancey Xavier Wyatt
Erika Yancey Wyatt Zeus Xavier Victor
```

So for instance, `men["Victor"] = ["Bertha","Amy","Diane","Erika","Clare"]`.

The code is in the file `GS.py` (an implementation of Gale-Shapley):

```
if __name__ == "__main__":

    ## Data Dictionary

    ''' Name : Preferences '''
    men = dict()
    women = dict()

    ''' List of unmatched men '''
    freeMen = list()

    ''' Name : How far down in preferences '''
    count = dict()

    ''' Name : Current Match '''
    wife = dict()
    husband = dict()

    ## Reading Input
    data = input("").split("\n")
    print(data)
    readingMen = True
    for l in data:
        line = l.split()
        print(line)
        if len(line) > 1:
            newPerson = line[0]
            newPersonPreferences = list()
            for i in range(1,len(line)):
                newPersonPreferences.append(line[i])
            if readingMen:
                print("man")
                print(newPersonPreferences)
                men[newPerson] = newPersonPreferences
                wife[newPerson] = 0
                count[newPerson] = 0
                freeMen.append(newPerson)
            else:
                print("woman")
                print(newPersonPreferences)
                women[newPerson] = newPersonPreferences
                husband[newPerson] = 0
        elif len(line) == 1:
            raise IOError(l + "\nis an invalid line.")
        else:
            readingMen = False

    ## Proposing
    while len(freeMen) != 0:
        m = freeMen[0]
        w = men[m][count[m]]
        count[m] += 1
        if husband[w] == 0:
            husband[w] = m
            wife[m] = w
            freeMen.remove(m)
        else:
            try:
                if women[w].index(husband[w], women[w].index(m)):
                    freeMen.append(husband[w])
                    wife[husband[w]] = 0
                    husband[w] = m
                    wife[m] = w
                    freeMen.remove(m)
            except ValueError:
                pass

    ## Match Printing
    print()
    for m in wife:
        print(m, wife[m])
```

When using IDLE on Windows, I just paste the contents of this file and hit enter, and it works.

But using Ubuntu, I do `python3 GS.py < names.txt` and I get this:

```
me@glados:~$ python3 GS.py < names.txt
['Victor Bertha Amy Diane Erika Clare']
['Victor', 'Bertha', 'Amy', 'Diane', 'Erika', 'Clare']
man
['Bertha', 'Amy', 'Diane', 'Erika', 'Clare']
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "GS.py", line 83, in <module>
    if husband[w] == 0:
KeyError: 'Bertha'
```

*(edited)* Now when I do `cat names.txt | python3 GS.py` I get this:

```
ajg9132@glados:~$ cat names.txt | python GS.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "GS.py", line 50, in <module>
    data = input("").split("\n")
  File "<string>", line 1
    Victor Bertha Amy Diane Erika Clare
                ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I've no idea what to do - kind of ignorant regarding I/O. Any help?

*Edit note:* I thought the two different bash commands I gave were equivalent, but then again, I'm a total noob, so an explanation for why they're different would help too...

To clear up ambiguity, this is for an Algo homework... (sad that I understand the algorithm but not the low-level details of the OS) and I need to have a specific input and output scheme. e.g.

```
spock $ java GS
Victor Bertha Amy Diane Erika Clare
Wyatt Diane Bertha Amy Clare Erika
Xavier Bertha Erika Clare Diane Amy
Yancey Amy Diane Clare Bertha Erika
Zeus Bertha Diane Amy Erika Clare

Amy Zeus Victor Wyatt Yancey Xavier
Bertha Xavier Wyatt Yancey Victor Zeus
Clare Wyatt Xavier Yancey Zeus Victor
Diane Victor Zeus Yancey Xavier Wyatt
Erika Yancey Wyatt Zeus Xavier Victor

Victor Amy
Wyatt Clare
Xavier Bertha
Yancy Erika
Zeus Diane
spock $
```

The only reason why I wasn't doing this was because pasting several lines of text into PuTTY made bash try to interpret each line as a command. I can't even.

Comment: Did you try to add some debug printing and see where and why this happens? I guess no one wants to mess around with your whole code.

Comment: I have a bad habit of removing all my debug statements as soon as my code works on one platform before I test it on another. Sure! BRB.

Comment: [KeyError](http://wiki.python.org/moin/KeyError) means it didnt find some data in the dictionary

Comment: Yes I know this, but it works on Windows and not Ubuntu, so I believe it has something to do with how input is taken on the different platforms.

Comment: Can it be related to different line endings for Ubuntu/Windows, \r\n vs \n ?

Comment: It could be. I strip via "\n" but you have a good point. What's a good platform-agnostic way to tackle it?

Comment: @bbaja42 is right I believe...

Comment: platform-agnostic split : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2596771/regex-to-split-on-successions-of-newline-characters

Comment: @bbaja42: I don't think it has anything to do with the line endings -- when I tested my much-simpler program, my `names.txt` had native line endings. `input()` normally just reads one line and I have no idea why IDLE would change that to allow `input()` to read more than one line. Go figure.

Comment: @bbaja42 I switch to splitlines() and it doesn't work. However the vertical bar attempt now matches the same erroneous output as the left carat attempt...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The meaning of `input()` has changed.

In Python 3.2: http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/functions.html#input

In Python 2.7.2: http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#input

You can see this far easier with two small testing programs. The only difference is one uses the Python 2.7 interpreter and the other uses the Python 3.2 interpreter:

```
$ cat input27.py 
#!/usr/bin/python2.7
data = input("")

for l in data.split("\n"):
    print(l)
$ cat input32.py 
#!/usr/bin/python3.2
data = input("")

for l in data.split("\n"):
    print(l)
$ ./input27.py < names.txt 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./input27.py", line 2, in <module>
    data = input("")
  File "<string>", line 1
    Victor Bertha Amy Diane Erika Clare
                ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
$ ./input32.py < names.txt 
Victor Bertha Amy Diane Erika Clare
$
```

Note that even though the Python 3.2 version doesn't throw errors, it also doesn't print all the lines in `names.txt` as one might expect.

I don't think the `input()` method is worth using. Easier would use the new-fangled [`for line in file:`](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#file.next) approach instead:

```
$ cat fixed_input27.py 
#!/usr/bin/python2.7

import sys

for line in sys.stdin:
    print(line.split()[0])
$ cat fixed_input32.py 
#!/usr/bin/python3.2

import sys

for line in sys.stdin:
    print(line.split()[0])
$ ./fixed_input27.py < names.txt 
Victor
Wyatt
Xavier
Yancey
Zeus
Amy
Bertha
Clare
Diane
Erika
$ ./fixed_input32.py < names.txt 
Victor
Wyatt
Xavier
Yancey
Zeus
Amy
Bertha
Clare
Diane
Erika
$
```

(I removed the one blank line from the `names.txt` because it caused this simple program to throw an error. It won't actually be an issue in your full-fledged program, because you properly handle the blank line.)

I can't explain why `input()` *did* work under Windows, but `input()` feels like a horrible enough interface (who thought running the user-supplied input through `eval` was a good idea?!? sheesh) to just re-write it.

**Update**

Okay, I was intrigued enough to solve this all the way. I took all your debugging code back out and switched to using the `for l in sys.stdin:` approach:

```
$ ./GS.py 
Victor Bertha Amy Diane Erika Clare
Wyatt Diane Bertha Amy Clare Erika
Xavier Bertha Erika Clare Diane Amy
Yancey Amy Diane Clare Bertha Erika
Zeus Bertha Diane Amy Erika Clare

Amy Zeus Victor Wyatt Yancey Xavier
Bertha Xavier Wyatt Yancey Victor Zeus
Clare Wyatt Xavier Yancey Zeus Victor
Diane Victor Zeus Yancey Xavier Wyatt
Erika Yancey Wyatt Zeus Xavier Victor

Wyatt Clare
Xavier Bertha
Yancey Erika
Zeus Diane
Victor Amy
$ cat GS.py 
#!/usr/bin/python3.2

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys

    ## Data Dictionary

    ''' Name : Preferences '''
    men = dict()
    women = dict()

    ''' List of unmatched men '''
    freeMen = list()

    ''' Name : How far down in preferences '''
    count = dict()

    ''' Name : Current Match '''
    wife = dict()
    husband = dict()

    ## Reading Input
    readingMen = True
    for l in sys.stdin:
        line = l.split()
        if len(line) > 1:
            newPerson = line[0]
            newPersonPreferences = list()
            for i in range(1,len(line)):
                newPersonPreferences.append(line[i])
            if readingMen:
                men[newPerson] = newPersonPreferences
                wife[newPerson] = 0
                count[newPerson] = 0
                freeMen.append(newPerson)
            else:
                women[newPerson] = newPersonPreferences
                husband[newPerson] = 0
        elif len(line) == 1:
            raise IOError(l + "\nis an invalid line.")
        else:
            readingMen = False

    ## Proposing
    while len(freeMen) != 0:
        m = freeMen[0]
        w = men[m][count[m]]
        count[m] += 1
        if husband[w] == 0:
            husband[w] = m
            wife[m] = w
            freeMen.remove(m)
        else:
            try:
                if women[w].index(husband[w], women[w].index(m)):
                    freeMen.append(husband[w])
                    wife[husband[w]] = 0
                    husband[w] = m
                    wife[m] = w
                    freeMen.remove(m)
            except ValueError:
                pass

    ## Match Printing
    print()
    for m in wife:
        print(m, wife[m])

$
```

Note that you have to hit `^D` when you're done pasting in the input if you run it this way. (I *much* prefer IO redirection `./GS.py < names.txt`, but if your professor will copy and paste, then make sure your prof knows to hit `^D` to signal the end of input.)

Comment: While I agree with your gripe about windows, I think that input() worked in windows because I pasted the text in the prompt in an IDLE session, which is different than piping (is that the word?) the contents of a file into an input stream. That said, I can't use your solution... I'll edit my question with the example input and output for this assignment.

Comment: Looked at your edit... it works indeed! ...On Ubuntu. On Windows I get this:

 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\yada yada\GS.py", line 52, in <module>
   for l in sys.stdin:
 TypeError: 'RPCProxy' object is not iterable`

Comment: Hahahahaha. Hilarious. I don't think I like IDLE much. :) Try replacing `for l in sys.stdin:` with `for l in sys.stdin.readlines():` -- perhaps IDLE's proxying will allow one of the older functions to work.

Comment: readlines() isn't actually a method of stdin as of Python 3... had this problem earlier.

Comment: Maybe [`fileinput`](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/fileinput.html) is the cross-platform mechanism to read from standard input?

Comment: I tried `fileinput` and it wasn't particularly helpful. It gave an AttributeError in IDLE.

Comment: Do you have to execute your program from within IDLE? From what I've seen here, IDLE seems like it might be a tolerable IDE but it looks _horrible_ as an execution environment. :(

Comment: I have to be able to cater to my CS department. They will run my code on Windows, OSX, Linux, or Solaris, from IDLE, the terminal, Eclipse, and just about anything else. I have to be able to run my code on the Solaris machines at least, but that doesn't always cut it. :(

Comment: The _best_ interface for utilities is to emulate utilities such as `cat(1)` -- read input from however many filenames are given as arguments on the command line and if there are no filename arguments on the command line, read input from the standard input stream. It's a real pity the IDLE environment makes this impossible to use. Perhaps the next best thing is to hardcode your sample data in a string variable in the script and allow the user to submit _new_ data through another mechanism if they want different input data. But you shouldn't have to fight your environment this much. :(

Comment: I actually turned to a command line argument approach, with prompting as a backup. It's not perfect, but it's versatile enough. Following this comment thread, even though your answer didn't perfectly solve my problem, it provided me enough knowledge about some of the ways to read data. Accepted.

Comment: That sounds suitable enough. Welcome to platform compatibility -- write once run anywhere! Today! :) Thanks, it's been educational for me too. :)